# Pandas dataframe indexing

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function that accepts a Pandas dataframe as an input. The frame has an identifier "id" and I want to process each unique identifier "id" separately and then write the result back to the input, in a separate colum. This works sometimes:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def process_data(indata):
    # Add new column
    indata = indata.join(pd.DataFrame({'result': []}))
    indata['result'] = False

    for id in np.unique(indata['id']):

        data_for_one_id = indata[indata['id'] == id]

        # Do some operations on the values, for instance this
        result = data_for_one_id['value'].to_numpy() >= 2

        # Write back to original array. TODO: How to do this properly?
        indata.loc[data_for_one_id.index, 'result'] = result

    return indata


indata = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],  'value': range(6)})
print("Before \r\n", indata)
outdata = process_data(indata)
print("After \r\n", outdata)
```

Which yields the result as expected

```
>>>Before 
    id  value
0   1      0
1   1      1
2   1      2
3   2      3
4   2      4
5   2      5
After 
    id  value  result
0   1      0   False
1   1      1   False
2   1      2    True
3   2      3    True
4   2      4    True
5   2      5    True
```

So this is the basic principle for how I do this but it doesn't work for all DataFrame indata. For instance,

```
indata.loc[data_for_one_id.index, 'result'] = result
```

sometimes produces

> Exception has occurred: ValueError Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

I guess data_for_one_id.index sometimes returns an iterator or so. I am quiet new to Pandas, and I guess what I wonder is, how to do this properly?

Comment: Can you specify when the particular exception occurs, maybe any example input ?

Comment: Why don't you use `df["result"] = (df["value"] >= 2)`?

Comment: I see @Shubham Sharma provided the answer. Just avoid loops, they are time and memory consuming, and take advantage of the optimized functionalities of `pandas`.

Comment: Yes for this toy example that would be the way to go. However, for my intents, each id marks single time series, and I need to consider each of these time series independently. The real data processing is something else than what I did in this example.